# Selecting based off of 2 dates in two separate column on another SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, date, select, between

I'm having issues with a subquery giving me this issue

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "reference..shift_begin_datetime" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "reference..shift_end_datetime" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "reference..mfg_ww_no" could not be bound.

The table that I'm trying to pull `mfg_ww_no` is on a table on another database. The only way I have to pull that is by matching `tracked_out_datetime` which falls between a `shift_begin_datetime` and a `shift_end_datetime`.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong.

This portion is the subquery that's giving me problems.

```
(Select
[reference]..[mfg_ww_no]
 From reference.dbo.ww_shift
 where 
     [tracked_out_datetime] between [reference]..[shift_begin_datetime] and         [reference]..[shift_end_datetime]) as ww
```

Here's the complete query for reference.

```
SELECT distinct TOP 1000  --*
    [lot_id] 
    ,[tracked_out_datetime]
    ,convert (varchar(20), S.facility_step_seq_no) + ' ' + convert(varchar(50), 
    STEP.step_name) as step_name
    ,datediff(mi, FLH.staged_datetime, FLH.tracked_out_datetime) - FLH.time_at_hold_seconds_value /60 as TrueCycleTime
    ,(Select
         [reference]..[mfg_ww_no]
      From reference.dbo.ww_shift
      where [tracked_out_datetime] between [reference]..[shift_begin_datetime] and [reference]..[shift_end_datetime]) as ww
from
fab_lot_extraction..fab_lot_hist FLH
INNER JOIN 
    traveler..trav_step TS ON FLH.trav_step_OID = TS.trav_step_OID
INNER JOIN 
    traveler..traveler TRAV ON TS.trav_OID = TRAV.trav_OID
INNER JOIN 
    traveler..step STEP ON TS.step_OID = STEP.step_OID
INNER JOIN 
    traveler..step_data_for_fab SDFAB ON TS.step_OID = SDFAB.step_OID
INNER JOIN 
    reference..mfg_area AREA ON SDFAB.mfg_area_OID = AREA.mfg_area_OID
INNER JOIN 
    reference..FP_step S ON STEP.step_OID = S.step_OID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    reference..FP_part_in_part_group PART ON FLH.part_type_code =  PART.part_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    reference..FP_part_group PG ON PART.part_group_OID =  PG.part_group_OID and
PG.mfg_facility_OID = 0x990FEE36400A9854
WHERE 
    FLH.[tracked_out_datetime] >= '20140405 19:000:0' and FLH.[tracked_out_datetime] < '20140406 19:000:0' 
    AND FLH.target_lot_sw = 'Y'
    and FLH.step_deleted_sw <> 'Y'
    and step_name like '%PHOTO ENG DISPO%'
ORDER BY
    3
```

Comment: what kind of database we talkin' here?!

Comment: Someone posted this and then deleted it.  It did fix the issue, so whoever posted that thank you.    ,(Select
  A.[mfg_ww_no]
        From reference.dbo.ww_shift A
        where [tracked_out_datetime] between A.[shift_begin_datetime] and A.[shift_end_datetime]) as ww

Comment: mysql? sql server? oracle? can we get a tag or a hint...?

Comment: I added tsql to the title when I posted.  This is Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, someone already answered the question, but it looks like you had a bad reference in your between clause:

```
where [tracked_out_datetime] between [reference]..[shift_begin_datetime] and [reference]..[shift_end_datetime]
```

Specifically this:

```
[reference]..[shift_begin_datetime]
```

The convention for referring to a column looks like this:

```
[database].[schema].[table].[column]
```

And you can shorten the default schema:

```
[database]..[table].[column]
```

So, I believe the query thought you were referencing tables and not an actual column. The answer you mentioned in your comments aliases the table and then you have correct column references.

```
,(Select A.[mfg_ww_no] From reference.dbo.ww_shift A where [tracked_out_datetime] between A.[shift_begin_datetime] and A.[shift_end_datetime]) as ww
```